# Discord Buttons on Embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Is anyone able to show me how I could add the discord Interactive Buttons onto this embed. I'm looking for just a simple button that will link somewhere. Thanks for the help

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const { Client, Message } = require('discord.js');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'text',
    cooldown: 1000,
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        message.delete()
        const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#000')
            .setAuthor("Text")
            .setDescription('Text')
            .addFields(
                {
                    name: `TextTitle`,
                    value: `Text`,
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: `TextTitle`,
                    value: `Text`
                }        )


        message.channel.send(exampleEmbed)}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you should call the `MessageButton` and `MessageActionRow`:

```js
const { MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require('discord.js');
```

Then we make a simple embed:

```js
        const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#000')
            .setAuthor({ name: "Text" })
            .setDescription('Text')
            .addFields(
                {
                    name: `TextTitle`,
                    value: `Text`,
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: `TextTitle`,
                    value: `Text`
                })
```

After that, We make a row and add some buttons to it:

```js
        const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setLabel('Invite') // label of the button
                    .setEmoji('➕') // emoji
                    .setURL('https://https://stackoverflow.com') // URL of where the button leads the user
                    .setStyle('LINK') // style of the button
            )
```

Then we send them:

```js
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed], components: [row] })
```

There are 5 styles of building buttons:
`PRIMARY`,
`SECONDARY`,
`SUCCESS`,
`DANGER`,
`LINK`

[image: styles]

Final Result:

[image: result]

You can visit Discordjs guides for [More Info on Buttons](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html)

**UPDATE:** Discord.js v12
For creating buttons in discord.js v12, We should import buttons from the `discord-buttons` package.

```js
const { MessageButton } = require('discord-buttons');
```

Then we make the button:

```js
let button = new MessageButton()
.setStyle('url')
.setURL('https://stackoverflow.com')
.setLabel('invite');
```

Then we send it:

```js
message.channel.send('test',button)
```

discord buttons v12 styles:

- `green`
- `red`
- `blurple`
- `url`

Comment: I seem to have an older version of discord.js, the v12. The command works but it doesn't send out the buttons, any way to link to discord-buttons? that seems to be the place where the MessageActionRow and MessageButton files are, but I was unable to find a way to do that

Comment: I added the v12 version too. check it out.